# GDI+ initialization crashes the app, why?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I have the following C++ line that obtains the GDI+ handle out of GDI's device context:

```
//HDC hDC = device context from GDI
if(hDC)
{
    //Obtain graphics handle for GDI++
    Graphics* pgrpx = new Graphics(hDC);    //I get invalid memory exception here

    //Code continues
    //...

    //Free object
    delete pgrpx;
    pgrpx = NULL;
}
```

It works just fine in my tests.

But recently I received a crash dump for the app, with the "thread referenced memory location that it has no access to" exception at the line I pointed above in the code -- right where the Graphics object is supposed to be initialized.

What could be the issue here? And how to address it?

Comment: Did you call the initialization functions that GDI+ provides?

Comment: Yes. Forgot to mention that. Is it Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup?

Comment: Something like that, but there's another one I'm thinking of as well (or maybe it was just the objects you need to create). I haven't used GDI+ too often, partially because of that extra hassle trying to remember (how) to initialize it.

Comment: @NathanMoinvaziri: The hDC comes from CreateCompatibleDC and I check it for not being NULL. But even if it isn't, can that Graphics constructor throw an exception?

Comment: Maybe the error is caused by the hDC being created on another thread.

Comment: @NathanMoinvaziri: No, hDC is created just a few lines of code earlier.

Comment: It is hard to see what could be causing it without more source code. I recommend you start with the simple example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077(v=vs.85).aspx and work your way up from there to where you are now.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that page myself. You see, the problem is that I can't replicate that exception. All I have is a crash dump from another Windows 7 and that's it. So what do you think, shall I put that constructor into __try{}__except(1){} block?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the initialization of the GDI+? I'm not sure if the problem lies here but you can give it a try.

```
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput    gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR                       gdiplusToken;
if(GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL) != Gdiplus::Ok)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("GDI+ failed to start up!"),
        TEXT("Error!"), MB_ICONERROR);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It's something that gets goofed up afterwards.